# Is MariaDB (MySQL) UNION atomic?

Tags: mysql, concurrency, transactions, mariadb, race-condition

Let's say I have two InnoDB tables - `TableA` and `TableB`. There is a single record in `TableB` and `TableA` is empty.

I also have two parallel processes.

`Process1` is looking for a row in either `TableA` or `TableB`. It executes two SQL statements - `select * from TableA` and then `select * from TableB`.

`Process2` wants to move the record from `TableB` to `TableA`. It starts a transaction and then performs the queries `delete from TableB` and `insert into TableA`.

Unfortunately there is a race condition here. If `Process2` makes its move while `Process1` is stalled somewhere between the two `select` statements then `Process1` will never see the row.

One way to solve this would be to swap the `select` statements around and first select from `TableB`. Together with the transaction and at least `READ COMMITED` isolation level that should be enough to detect the record in at least one table.

However I was wondering if a `select * from TableA union all select * from TableB` would also do the trick? I think it would reduce the involved parts and make it less likely to break with future code changes (no need to worry about statement order). But does it eliminate the race condition?

If it matters, assume the latest MariaDB version.

Answer (score 0):

Test each of these:

Plan A:  The UNION that you suggest.

Plan B:  Wrap the `SELECTs` in a transaction and use `FOR UPDATE` on each.

Plan C:  Wrap in a transaction and use isolation mode `SERIALIZABLE`.  I tend to prefer this one because it indicates that you really can't have two threads touching these tables at the same time.

Caveat:  I do not know which ones will / won't work.

Comment: Hmm... The union is kinda hard to test because setting up the race condition will be very much up to luck and factors I don't really know. The `for update` (plus a transaction) would work I think (since it would lock), but in that case either I risk a deadlock or the order of the selects becomes important again. And `SERIALIZABLE` reduces to the `for update` case.

Comment: You should always code for the possibility of errors, including deadlocks.

Comment: No transactions - no deadlocks!  Although you're right of course. I was trying to reduce locking however, sticking to simple autocommit statements and using optimistic locking instead. Collisions should be rare. Although in that case maybe it shouldn't matter and I can just use regular transactions with regular locks? I'll... have to think about it.

Comment: @Vilx- - `LOCK TABLE` should not be used with InnoDB.  Autocommit includes locks.

Comment: No, no, you misunderstand me. I don't mean to lock the whole table! That would be a disaster. I mean locking the record in `TableB`. Both processes would start with `select ... from TableB for update` and then only one of them would work at a time. A very simple solution and really simplifies many other things too... except that sometimes the record isn't there and then it's the process' job to create it. What happens then? If I can solve that part, I'm good.

Comment: Without the `FOR UPDATE`, they both might try to create it.  With `FOR UPDATE`, one will be able to create; the other will delay, then discover that it exists.  Read about "gap locking".

Comment: I just tested and... it's not good. When both do a `select ... for update` for a non-existent row, both selects complete just fine and return an empty result set. But they both now hold a shared lock on the gap. If either one tries to insert, it blocks. When the other one tries to insert, a deadlock is detected. The second one is shot down (exception) and the first one succeeds. I... guess it's workable, but I don't like it. Perhaps there's another way...

Comment: Hence, you must check for deadlocks and write code to recover.  _It is not possible to prevent all deadlocks._

Comment: Maybe. But I'll try anyway. :D At least for a little while, until I run out of ideas. To be honest, even when I've needed to use transactions (and it's not often), I've never had to worry about deadlocks yet. How do I even detect them? It'll be an error, sure, but how do I distinguish a deadlock from other errors? Right now I got error code 1213, but will it always be the same? And that part where an insert blocks until the _other_ transaction tries to do an insert... that's not cool either. If you're the first one, I want you to succeed immediately and not waste time. The other one can wait.

Comment: Actually, the gap lock is an even bigger disaster. Not only does it block the other transaction that wants to insert the same row, it will block ALL transactions that try to insert rows in that gap, even unrelated rows.

Comment: Hmm, I think I figured it out. I do start a transaction, but after that I do a `insert into TableB ... on duplicate key update...`. This ensures that there is a row and takes a lock on that row and only on that row. Then I check all that I need to check. If there is a record in `TableA`, I rollback and abort. Otherwise I continue mucking around in `TableA` and/or `TableB` and everything else waits until I either commit or rollback. And there's no deadlocks because nobody else tries to write to those tables.

Comment: Nope... no luck. Turns out `insert ... on duplicate key update` STILL creates gap locks. And my original plan about optimistic locking could in theory lead to an infinite loop between two competing processes. Thus, the only solution left - a separate `TableLock`. Upon the start of the process I start a transaction and insert a single row with a precise primary key. Before committing the row gets deleted. Same about rollback. And any other transactions will block and wait for that precise key to become available, and no gap locks. Tested it.

Comment: InnoDB does not avoid extra locks in all cases.  Live with it.